# Is there any ways to connect flutter app to odoo 13?

Tags: flutter, odoo

How to connect flutter app to odoo 13? Is there any ways to connect flutter app to odoo 13?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `XMLRPC` or `JSONRPC` as External API of Odoo to connect your Odoo from any services. For more details about this you can follow the [official documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/misc/api/odoo.html#external-api). [Odoo RPC Client Library](https://pub.dev/packages/odoo_rpc) in dart is also available for use. Once you have the basic idea how RPC External API works, you can combine this two to achieve what you need.

Comment: ok thank you bro

Comment: That's a good answer. You can create `controllers` to expose REST services from odoo, and connect to this with `http` or `dart:io` class too.